# Make one position in an array equal a new object

Tags: java, arrays, object

How to make one position in an array equal a new object?

```
public SalesItem findItem(String itemCode){

    SalesItem[] item = new SalesItem();
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {

        if(itemCode.equals(items[i].getItemCode())){
            if(items[i].getQuantity() > 0) {
                item = items[i];
                items[i].setQuantity(items[i].getQuantity()-1);
            }
    }
 return item;
}
```

I'm trying to find the position in the array contains the string "itemCode" and then use that position of the array to make it equal to the new item that i've declared so that i can then return the new item to be added to a shopping basket.

I know I'm not doing something right with the SalesItem object, but I don't know what.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This code is missing parts and also has OBVIOUS compilation errors...

Comment: You're missing a "}". Is this a mistake in your code or in your post ?

Comment: @anshulkatta  Please don't suggest edits to a question that 'fix' things.  That is less than helpful.

Comment: the size is just the number of different items available in the shop.
And i just missed a curly bracket in the post.

Comment: @AndrewThompson...it was an object , now it is fixed

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring an array of SalesItems instead of one object, so the declaration of `item` should probably be like this:

```
SalesItem item = new SalesItem();
```

Edit: You may also want to remove the creation of the new object entirely, since it will not be used after `item` is assigned the value of `items[i]`. So just declare it like this:

```
SalesItem item = null;
```

After `item = items[i]`, `item` will contain a reference to the object in the array you were looking for, or null if it was not found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that other parts of your code are correct (e.g. `getQuantity()` and `setQuantity()` in `SalesItem`), the only mistake I can see is this:

```
SalesItem[] item = new SalesItem();
```

I think you simply wanted to do:

```
SalesItem item = null;
```

Such that `findItem()` will return `null` if no item matches the `itemCode` you are looking for.